# How do I properly stream media from a local http server running on my laptop to other devices on my WiFi network?

Tags: networking, python, webserver, python3, multimedia

So I am running a simple http server on a certain directory on my laptop (say Music/), with `python -m http.server` - the command starts up a server on my machine with port `8000`.

I proceed to look up my local IP with `ip addr | grep inet` and then I punch in `192.168.my.ip` on an android  - everything runs fine, the directory loads and I can view and download files from my phone using `192.168.my.ip:8000`. The only problem is that when I *play* any movies or songs, the little media player thing that pops up on my browser cant scrub forwards or backwards, the only controls available to me are mute/unmute, play/pause, fullscreen and download.

I am positive that my browser (on the android) is not the issue since it can play music/media files over the "normal" internet perfectly fine and both the firefox and chrome browser-inbuilt media player have this issue.

So what do I have to do to be able to play the media files through my android (or any other device running a browser) in a full-featured manner?

My laptop is running python 3.9.2 on Arch Linux with Linux kernel 5.11.7.

Thanks,

Comment: When you access a file on the web server, it just downloads the data. There is no function to go back or fast-forward; the web server just sends one byte after the other. You need a media server on your laptop. A bit of googling will yield many solutions. Since you use Python: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/4go8n4/how_can_i_set_up_a_youtubestyle_video_server/.